# Validation failed for one or more entities. UserManager.AddToRole()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm developing a Web Api using ASP.NET MVC5 and I have successfully implemented a Custom IdentityUser.Like So

```
public partial class Authentication : IdentityUser
{
    public Authentication()
    {
        this.LoginSessions = new List<LoginSession>();
    }
    [Required]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lecturer Lecturer { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LoginSession> LoginSessions { get; set; }
}
```

with the following Maps

```
public class IdentityUserLoginConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{
    public IdentityUserLoginConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.UserId);
    }
}

public class IdentityRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole>
{
    public IdentityRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
public class AuthenticationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Authentication>
{
    public AuthenticationMap()
    {

        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.PersonId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.PersonId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(14);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Authentication");
        this.Property(t => t.PersonId).HasColumnName("PersonID");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Lecturer)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Authentication);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Student)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.Authentication);


    }
}
```

But now my problem is that when I'm adding a user to a Role Using the

```
UserManager.AddToRole()
```

method I get a DBValidationError 
This is really worrying me and would like some help as soon as possible

Comment: What is the validation error?

Comment: Sorry It said and EntityValidation Error

Comment: What that usually means is that a property not marked as nullable is attempting to be saved into the database as null. Debug and catch the error and drill down into the error to see what property it is.

Comment: After careful Analysis I found the Error Entity is IdentityUserRole